# Using sum of checked items' values from wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I tried to place this code in wordpress loop: it should check checkbox's status for each post by id and if they checked - update value of textarea (it should to update after each click on checkboxes). 
but it catch value of the last post only.. although it looks right in page-view-source (all IDs on its places)

```
<!--wp loop begin-->
<!--post content-->
  <script>    
    $('.taglist input').click(function() {
    var sum=0;
    if (document.getElementById('<?php the_ID(); ?>').checked){sum+=1000;}     
    $('textarea').val(sum)
    ;}
    );
  </script>
<!--wp loop end-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `sum` variable outside of the wordpress loop.

```
<script>var sum = 0;</script>
<!--wp loop begin-->
<!--post content-->
  <script>    
    $('.taglist input').click(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('<?php the_ID(); ?>').checked) {
             sum+=1000;
        } else {
            sum-=1000;
        }
        $('textarea').val(sum);
    });
  </script>
<!--wp loop end-->
```

Also, I'm guessing you need to remove 1000 from the sum if someone unchecked a checkbox.

Actually, a neater way might be to add the php id variable to an array in the loop, and then do everything else outside the loop -

```
<script>
    var sum = 0;
    var checkboxIdArray = [];
</script>
<!--wp loop begin-->
<!--post content-->
  <script>
    checkboxIdArray.push('<?php the_ID(); ?>');
  </script>
<!--wp loop end-->
<script>

    $('.taglist input').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (typeof checkboxIdArray[id] !== 'undefined') {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                sum+=1000;
                } else {
                    sum-=1000;
                }
            $('textarea').val(sum);
        }
    });

</script>
```

UPDATE

OK, You don't need to use the php variable at all - you just need the to use `$(this)` inside the click callback, as suggested by Mihai Iorga.

Comment: This will still result in only the last element being checked. The solution is to either bind by `the_ID()` or use `$(this)` as in Mihais answer.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I don't think OP is trying to check checkboxes - he's trying to insert a single value into a textarea. (this value is based on the number of checkboxes checked).

Comment: correct, but your first solution still only checks if the last checkbox is checked. Your second soluton is basically the same as Mihais answer, just overly complicated.

Comment: Aidan, thanks a lot! Looks Like it's working fine to me.
But what about using radio instead checkboxes?

Comment: either radio or checkboxes should work fine (obviously you'll need different code to identify the radio value)

Comment: yeah, but if I click radio twice - it sum value twice (

Answer (score 2):

You should place this code outside the loop and bind the click on each element, as you are already doing:

```
<!--wp loop begin-->
<!--post content-->

<!--wp loop end-->
<script>    
    $('.taglist input').click(function() {
        var sum=0;
        if ($(this).checked){
                sum+=1000;
        } 
        $('textarea').val(sum);
    });
</script>
```

But I think you would want to do more something like this:

```
<!--wp loop begin-->
<!--post content-->

<!--wp loop end-->
<script>   
var sum = 0;
$('.taglist input').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
        sum+=1000;
    } else {
        sum-=1000;
    }
    $('textarea').val(sum);
});
</script>
```

If checkbox is unchecked .. I think it should subtract.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7575ho35/)

Comment: OK - I like it (and I get it - the php variable was a red herring - OP just wanted a way of saying 'this'). You still need to stop assigning sum to 0 inside the click callback (in your first code block). +1 from me.